# Best way to process withdrawals for ETH?

Tags: web3js, wallets, javascript

New to ETH. Designing a web-wallet type of service. Currently generating new deposit address keypairs via `web3.eth.personal.newAccount()`. Iterating each block via `web3.eth.getBlock()`, and scanning the transaction array for transactions where `tx.to == <deposit address>`. Watching for confirmations based on block height, using `web3.get().eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders')`.

This all seems to work fine, but I can't seem to easily figure out the best way to process withdrawals. I need to provide a `from` address when calling `web3.eth.sendTransaction({from, to, value})`

User balance is not linked to their deposit amount, it can change. So, is the best way to process a withdrawal to sweep all deposits to a common account address? What's the best way to do this? (i.e. gas considerations, etc)

Comment: It is a little unclear your goal here. Can you provide a user story you are trying to satisfy, and the current issue you are facing which impedes that user story?

Comment: User story: Have a balance of Eth, try to withdraw funds. I was just wondering if combining user balances together into a common hot wallet is the way to go here.

Comment: Withdraw funds, as in transfer from one wallet to another? Or are you controlling a smart contract which stores funds for the user which they can later take out again?

Comment: Transfer from my wallet to theirs.

Comment: Only you can initiate a transfer of your funds to another person's wallet, unless you use a smart contract as a kind of escrow account. It is my opinion that you have not spent enough effort to explain your scenario, or the challenges you are trying to overcome in your original post. My suggestion is to explain to us as if we do not know anything about what you are trying to build or what your assumptions are... because we do not.